# How not to change the web page URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to set the href value of a button relative to the current page url using jQuery mobile.

So I naively wrote the following code :

```
var path = window.location;
path = path.replace( "shop","edit" );
$("#btnEdit").setAttr( "href", path );
```

The url of the page is *http://mysite/shop/1* and the href of the button should be set to *http://mysite/edit/1*.

When this code is inserted at the top of my 'pageinit' handler I see the url in the location bar of the browser (firefox & chrome) changing to *http://mysite/shop/shop* and the page is apparently reloaded, so I get a 404 error since it must have a number after /shop/ and it should have the value 1.

Even if I comment it out, restart the web server, the browser automatically replaces the *http://mysite/shop/1* with the *http://mysite/shop/shop* in its url location field. ?!

I have to comment these instructions, restart the server and whatever to avoid this url replacement.

What is going on ?
How can I get the page location url and set my button href value without this nasty side effect ?

---

**Edit 1:**

1. I should indeed use **.attr** or **.prop** instead of .setAttr that doesn't exist.
2. The url change only show up with chrome and firefox, not in iPad, Android or IE9. Running the chrome debugging tool, it seems there is a DOMException thrown by jQuery at the instruction *matches.call( document.documentElement, "[test!='']:sizzle" );*. I have no idea what it means and why it causes the page to be reloaded with a different url.

---

**Edit 2:**

1. I'm using fapws as web server and mako for templates. After I erased the cached python files generated by mako, the url change disappeared. ?!
2. as suggested I should use **.attr** and **window.location.href**. This worked and the href attribute of the button was set to the correct value.
3. Though it still doesn't work as it should. I now see a new unexpected and undesirable behavior. When clicking on the button, the url in the location bar is changed into *http://mysite/edit/1*, it executes the pageinit of the shop page (?!), then loads the edit page without executing its pageinit event.

---

**Solution:**

In the html file I defined this button with a default href value and nothing special:

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="pencil" id="btnEdit"> Edit </a>
```

In the script file, more precisely in the handler of the $(document).on('pageinit',...) I now have this code which sets the href value but also adds the rel="external" attribute to the button.

```
var path = window.location.href;
path = path.replace( "shop","edit" );
$("#btnEdit").attr( "href", path ).attr( "rel", "external" );
```

There are no more automatic reload of the page and the weird behavior of the load has been removed. It happened because the default behavior of the <a> tag in jQuery Mobile is to load the target page using ajax and not with a normal full page load. The attribute rel="external" disables this behavior and the referenced page is then fully loaded normally. This behavior is described in the jQM documentation [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html).

*Note*: Although many answers contributed concretely to help me solve this problem, I checked Mad Man Moon's answer because he was very helpful and had the less points. If it was possible to check multiple answers I would have done it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Even if I comment **it** out, restart the web server, the browser
>   automatically replaces the ~/shop/1 with the
>   ~/shop/shop in its url location field. ?!
>
> I have to comment these instructions, restart the server and whatever
>   to avoid this url replacement.

1. I am a little confused. What is "it" that you are commenting out?
2. Even with your replace being executed against your variable reference to window.location, it should be replacing "shop" with "edit", so the re-direct should be "mysite/edit/1" (unless the js regex engine is treating the 1 as the capture index?)
3. Based on your RESTful style URL, I suspect that you are using some sort of server side MVC framework. If so, there's a good chance that the redirect is a server side issue and has nothing to do with the replace.
4. Finally, instead of setting path = window.location, set it equal to **window.location.href**. window.location is the **object** which contains the URI properties (href, search, hash, etc). window.location.href is the string property of the complete the URL.

EDIT: I decided to do a little test of my own and confirmed that the issue is that you are setting path = window.location. Set **path = window.location.href** and your code will work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. 1) The 'it' are the three lines of code shown above. 2) Yes. This is confusing. The other confusing thing is that on my iPad and android phone the url is not modified and I can see the page. 3) I use fapws python wsgi. I'm not sure it is on the server side. The problem doesn't show up with iPad, Android's browser & internet explorer. 4) I will be glad to try this once the url path change is corrected.

Comment: The problem came some how from the server. fapws generates some cached python file. I removed them and the url rewriting problem was gone. I didn't looked into the files. The suggestion in your Edit section also worked. I now get the correct url. But when I click on it, it seems the pageinit event is not triggered.

Comment: Is the code above, which adds the click event handler, being added after the DOM is loaded? Whether it be at the end of the body tag or within $(document).ready()?

Comment: The code above is in the pageinit event handler of the shop page. Even if I set the href of the button in the shop page (html) to the edit page url, when I click the button, the pageinit handler of the shop page is called, and when the edit page is loaded, its initpage handler is not called.

Comment: A more weird behavior is that if I reload the page edit page, its pageinit event is called and the content is initialized and shown. If I then click the back button of the browser, it should show the shop window. But what I see is that it is the pageinit of the edit page that is called, then the shop page is displayed and its pageinit event is not generated.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) instead of `setAttr` *(unless you are not using custom function or some framework/library)*

```
$("#btnEdit").attr( "href", path );
```

As for URL automatically changing, see if you have URL Rewriting put in place in `.htaccess` file or possibility of code which is changing the URL in some other file.

Comment: That's right. But I still see url change. I can't remove it even after commenting out the code. I used the url with edit which doesn't show this behavior. So there is probably a bug somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var path = window.location;
path = path.replace( "shop","edit" );
$("#btnEdit").prop( "href", path );
```

Comment: You are right, my code above was bogus. I should have use .attr or .prop. I'm now focussing on my url change and reload problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `path` is acting as an alias for `window.location`, so `path.replace()` is `window.location.replace()`, which triggers a redirect.

The solution: add `.toString()` on the end of `window.location` to get the string value instead of the object. `var path = window.location.toString()`

Comment: I suspected this. But apparently I should use the windows.location.href. This works without generating a redirect.